# Cloud Data Fusion: Oracle data type issues

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-data-fusion

In Cloud Data Fusion, i am using oracle plugin provided to get data from Oracle 18c database. When using this for source, I able to successfully extract varchar data, but the number/integer types are not successful.
Oracle table values are:

```
|ID (int) | NAME(varchar2) |
----------------------------
|501      | raja           |
|502      | praveen        |
```

Preview on DataFusion shows as below, notice the ID column, the values are different :

```
|ID(decimal)  | NAME (string)  |
--------------------------------
|[1,-11]      | raja           |
|[1,-10]      | praveen        |
```

What are these values [1,-11].
For decimals in oracle table, i get values like [0,-61,-66].
Any ideas about implicit conversion of number types in data fusion. I'm using the oracle drivers provided by Data fusion.

Comment: Making more awareness to the developers group on the reported plugin conversion mismatch I would recommend to file the request in the relevant [data-integrations](https://github.com/data-integrations/database-plugins/tree/develop/oracle-plugin) project.

Comment: thanks. I've posted a request on github.

Comment: decimals are internally represented as byte arrays, which is why they are showing up as an array of numbers in preview. This should be fixed in the upcoming versions (see https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-16754)

Comment: Thank you @AlbertShau

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the way the `decimal` data type is represented on Spark. If you are ingesting an integer value, I recomend you use `long` or `int` data type in Data Fusion. If you want to convert the integer to a decimal type representation or ingesting a decimal value where precision is ot very important, you can try ingesting it in floating point type, using the `float` data type.